# how to validate access token and redirect user if expired to refreshtoen view in simple jwt authentication with django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

How can i redirect user to obtain new access token in refresh token view if access token is expired ?
i implemented cookie based authentication with simple jwt library in django rest framework.
refresh token and access token are finely generated. But i have to verify the token for example if a user logged in, he recieved an access token . and when he is trying to add a new post. i have to firstly verify if the access token is not expired. if not expired then he could add the post, otherwise i will regnerate a new access token based on his refresh token already received.

Views.py

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = request.data
        response = Response()        
        email = data.get('email', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                data = get_tokens_for_user(user)
                response.set_cookie(
                    key = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE'], 
                    value = data["access"],
                    expires = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME'],
                    secure = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE'],
                    httponly = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY'],
                    samesite = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE']
                )
                csrf.get_token(request)
                response.data = {"Success" : "Login successfully","data":data}
                return response
            else:
                return Response({"No active" : "This account is not active!!"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        else:
            return Response({"Invalid" : "Invalid email or password!!"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

authenticate.py

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework.authentication import CSRFCheck
from rest_framework import exceptions

def enforce_csrf(request):
    check = CSRFCheck()
    check.process_request(request)
    reason = check.process_view(request, None, (), {})
    if reason:
        raise exceptions.PermissionDenied('CSRF Failed: %s' % reason)

class CustomAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        header = self.get_header(request)
        
        if header is None:
            raw_token = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE']) or None
        else:
            raw_token = self.get_raw_token(header)
        if raw_token is None:
            return None

        validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
        enforce_csrf(request)
        return self.get_user(validated_token), validated_token
```

urls.py

```
if api_settings.JWT_AUTH_COOKIE:
    from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
    from rest_framework_jwt.serializers import RefreshJSONWebTokenSerializer
    from rest_framework_jwt.views import RefreshJSONWebToken

    RefreshJSONWebTokenSerializer._declared_fields.pop('token')

    class RefreshJSONWebTokenSerializerCookieBased(RefreshJSONWebTokenSerializer):
        def validate(self, attrs):
            if 'token' not in attrs:
                if api_settings.JWT_AUTH_COOKIE:
                    attrs['token'] = JSONWebTokenAuthentication().get_jwt_value(self.context['request'])
            return super(RefreshJSONWebTokenSerializerCookieBased, self).validate(attrs)

    RefreshJSONWebToken.serializer_class = RefreshJSONWebTokenSerializerCookieBased

urlpatterns = [
    
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path('refresh/',TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name="refresh"),

]
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
      'api.authenticate.JWTAuthentication',
  ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    

}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]

SIMPLE_JWT = {
  'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
  'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
  'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
  'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
  'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

  'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
  'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
  'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
  'AUDIENCE': None,
  'ISSUER': None,

  'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
  'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
  'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
  'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
  'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

  'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
  'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

  'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

  'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
  'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
  'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),

  # custom
  'AUTH_COOKIE': 'access_token',  # Cookie name. Enables cookies if value is set.
  'AUTH_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None,     # A string like "example.com", or None for standard domain cookie.
  'AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE': False,    # Whether the auth cookies should be secure (https:// only).
  'AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY' : True, # Http only cookie flag.It's not fetch by javascript.
  'AUTH_COOKIE_PATH': '/',        # The path of the auth cookie.
  'AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE': 'Lax',  # Whether to set the flag restricting cookie leaks on cross-site requests. This can be 'Lax', 'Strict', or None to disable the flag.
}
```

Comment: The refresh token should also be sent to the user so that when the original request fails (from a 403 response), the frontend will know to make a token refresh call on the API before making the original request to the API again. If you're using axios, this would typically be done by implementing an interceptor.

Comment: yes, i'm sending the refresh token also to the user , so i need to handle it on the frontend side ? if token expired, i have to do another request to generate new access token ? but i read that i can implement a middleware in django to do, i don't know to do it , and i don't have a view that validates the token

Comment: If the access token is expired, DRF will return a 401 or 403 reponse to your frontend. It's one of the two... can't remember which one exactly. You can then configure your frontend to make a refresh token request where a new access token is generated for the user. There's actually no need to create a view to validate the tokens because if the access token is expired, you'll get a 401/403 on your original request and if the refresh token is expired, then you'll also get a 401/403 on the refresh request.

Comment: If you're using axios in your frontend, here's a [package](https://github.com/Flyrell/axios-auth-refresh) you can use for auth refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it can helps you:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import UntypedToken

# This will automatically validate the token and raise an error if token is invalid
data = UntypedToken(token)
```